# How to change Rails Admin query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.2

We have a large table and need to tweak a few queries on an index page.

I looked through the Wiki and SO and did not find any answers.

How do to change the query?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: _"need to tweak a few queries"_ - Can you put some light on this?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale - Where exactly do I put the code to change a query?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - One query is `SELECT COUNT(*)`. I want to change this to `SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class`. Another change is that when a user with certain privilege sees an index page, it does not render the total number of records.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to execute custom SQL, you can do so using `find_by_sql` like this:

```
Post.find_by_sql "SELECT p.title, c.author FROM posts p, comments c WHERE p.id = c.post_id"
```

More info here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Comment: I know how to do `find_by_sql`, but I am looking for a way to update Rails Admin to use it.

Answer (score 0):

add pagination and make sure that you're doing eager loading to prevent n+1 issues.

```
 @users = User.where.not(customer_id: nil).where(deleted_date: nil).
order('users.name').eager_load(:role).eager_load(:customer)
.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Example user query with role and customers.  Be sure to add the relationship in model.